# Can DNS's & CentOS handle subdomain of subdomain out of the box?

Tags: dns, centos, subdomain, cpanel

A regular subdomain is `foo.website.com`. Is it possible to have `foo.bar.website.com`? Do DNS's and/or web hosts allow this? Will Linux servers (specifically Cent OS) handle this by default or will it require bespoke configuration?

**Context**
We have a funny legacy setup. Our main domain for our server is `foo.website.com`. And url/domain pulls from the `public_html` folder. We now want to setup `staging.foo.website.com` that pulls from another folder `staging.foo.website.com` in the users home directory.

Comment: Attempt to explain your goal or end result of the changes, and provide snippets of the configuration file(s) you wish to modify, assuming you know which one(s) to edit.  That way others can help guide you to your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is so generic, my answer has to be as well.

Ahem, It's all in how the lookups are handled by your webserver!

1) DNS has no trouble allowing an "A" record to resolve to foo.website.com, and another "A" record to resolve to foo.bar.website.com, or even foo.foo.website.com.  I currently have a "foo.foo.com" which resolves differently than a "foo.com" will.  DNS is almost never the problem. A simple test to determine the answer is:

```
    nslookup foo.bar.website.com
```

and compare it to:

```
    nslookup foo.website.com
```

and check the results (assuming you have two different machines answering, or two different IPs assigned to the names.)  If they are the same, on purpose, then DNS doesn't factor into the equation.

2) No, it won't come that way out of the box.  They rarely have things preconfigured for domain names.  Just be sure to define "foo.bar.website.com" before "foo.website.com", and most things will test in the proper order.  However, if your URL request looks like:

```
    http://foo/
```

instead of:

```
    http://foo.bar.website.com/
```

Then you'd better hope the web server knows which FOO you are talking about, and it picks the right one every time.

3) This is one of many reasons why ReWriteModules are so very important and useful.  Syntactically, the rules should state the fully qualified domain name, so that there aren't any misinterpretations.  Tools like Concrete5 would expect fully unique foo.bar.website.com.conf files, just to manage such things.

Please review your web hosting service documentation, and the existing configuration.  Save a copy of the httpd.conf (just not in same directory please, as some web services consider it "another service to be run!") and make a simple edit, then restart and see where it takes you.  Put the originals back when you are done.